# Width of Table cell based on colgroup not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

Setting width for table cell using colgroup not works in IE9

```
<table id="Grid1_Table" class="Table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:20px">
        <col style="width:20px">
        <col style="width:180px">
        <col style="width:200px">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="RowHeader"><div>&nbsp;</div></td>
            <td class="RecordPlusCollapse"><div>&nbsp;</div></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="GroupCaption">Order ID: 0 - 1 Items</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.RowHeader
{
    background-color : black;
}
.GroupCaption
{ 
    background-color : #868981;
}
.RecordPlusCollapse
{
    background-color : red;
}
.Table{
    width: 100%;
}
```

First 2 `<td>` width is not as `colgroup` in IE9. Not sure why width differs.

http://jsfiddle.net/KgfsM/3/

Comment: @Sridar Narsimhan If you agree with the answer, it'd be great if you accept it by clicking the check mark symbol. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 23):

You are giving the table *100% width* and then go for *fixed width cols*. Where should the browser take the missing width from? It simply stretches the table cells.

Look at this example, works in every major browser, starting with IE 5(!) :)
http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/ppRgV/1/

Changes were stripping `width: 100%;` from table and adding [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

```
.Table {
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```